# CentOS 5.6 profile messed up?

Tags: centos, ssh, users, profile

I am running CentOS 5.6 on a dedicated server. I have accidentally removed the profile files from:

```
/home/USER123
```

There is only the following files in that directory:

- .bash_history
- .gitconfig
- /.ssh
- /var

Since the other files (I'm presuming there were other files) have been removed the prompt now shows:

```
-bash-3.2$
```

Is there a way of repairing this so it goes back to showing:

```
USER123@SERVERNAME
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The system default dot-files usually exist under /etc/skel, so you could try to make a copy of those into the users home-directory.

Answer (score 0):

It show -bash-3.2$ because the link don't work anymore. Try Recreating another user, maybe that'll fix the problem.